# How can I manipulate the slices of an image separately using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

I am new to the "canvas" term in HTML. I sliced a picture in 2 halves, leaving a small gap between them. I want to rotate each half separately to create a half folding effect.

```js
window.onload = function () {
            var myCanv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = myCanv.getContext('2d');
            var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
            context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.width / 2, myImage.height, 0, 0, myCanv.width / 2, myCanv.height);
            context.drawImage(myImage, (myImage.width / 2) + 1, 0, myImage.width / 2, myImage.height, (myCanv.width / 2) + 0.5, 0, myCanv.width / 2, myCanv.height);
        };
```

Is there any way that I can do this using canvas? I appreciate any help. :)

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9771a9ro/3/) I know it's not much but any hint is useful.

Comment: send half of the image to an invisible other canvas, send the other half to another invisible canvas, rotate each canvas using 'context.rotate()', then context.drawImage(InvisibleCanvas1, x, y), and context.drawImage(InvisibleCanvas2, x, y) to the visible canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to skew the 2 halves of the image rather than rotate them.

To skew you can use `context.transform` or `context.setTransform`.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var skewLeft=.1;
var skewRight=-.1;
var cx=100;
var y=30;
var iw,ih;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.jpg";
function start(){
  iw=img.width;
  ih=img.height;
  draw();
}

function draw(){

  // fill the canvas background with gray
  ctx.fillStyle='gray';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillStyle='black'

  // draw the left skewed page with a stroked border
  ctx.setTransform(1,skewLeft,0,1,cx,0);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iw/2,ih,-iw/2,y,iw/2,ih);
  ctx.strokeRect(-iw/2,y,iw/2,ih);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  // draw the right skewed page with a stroked border
  ctx.setTransform(1,skewRight,0,1,cx,0);
  ctx.drawImage(img,iw/2,0,iw/2,ih,0,y,iw/2,ih);
  ctx.strokeRect(0,y,iw/2,ih);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
img,#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Original Image (left) and<br>Image halved, skewed & bordered to look like a fold</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.jpg'>
<canvas id="canvas" width=225 height=150></canvas>
```